# jQuery UI datepicker ignores format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Code:

```
    $('.datepicker').each(function(){
        $(this).find('input').datepicker({
            dateFornat: 'dd.mm.yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
```

Result:

[image]

But according `dateFormat` it should be `12.10.2012`. Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dateFornat: 'dd.mm.yy',
```

Should be

```
dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
```

You misspelled it.

Comment: Thanks that was actually the reason :D